# rails select maximum value from array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

i have a array of hashes like this and i want to take the maximum value of that

```
data = [{name: "abc", value: "10.0"}, {name: "def", value: "15.0"}, {name: "ghi", value: "20.0"}, {name: "jkl", value: "50.0"}, {name: "mno", value: "30.0"}]
```

i want to select the maximum value of array of hashes, output i want is like data: "50.0"

how possible i do that, i've try this but it is seem doesnt work and just give me an error

```
data.select {|x| x.max['value'] }
```

any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are lots of ways of doing this in Ruby. Here are two. You could pass a block to `Array#max` as follows:

```
  > data.max { |a, b| a[:value] <=> b[:value] }[:value]
   => "50.0"
```

Or you could use `Array#map` to rip the `:value` entries out of the `Hash`:

```
  > data.map { |d| d[:value] }.max
   => "50.0"
```

Note that you might want to use `#to_f` or `Float(...)` to avoid doing String-String comparisons, depending on what your use case is.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version of [kranzky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27835111/3334827) answer:

```
data.map(&:value).max
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort the array of hashes and get the values by index.

```
array = array.sort_by {|k| k[:value] }.reverse

puts array[0][:value]
```

Useful if you need minimum, second largest etc. too.